# is there any facility to plot a line?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I have some nodes and I want to plot them.  some of them connect to others. I don't know How can I plot a line in Julia ? would you please help me?

for example a line as follow:

`y=2x+5`

thank you

Comment: Do you plan to plot a trendline on your data points or just a line?

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to the answer above, actually in Plots.jl it is even simpler. Just pass a function to `plot` like this:

```
plot(x->2x+5)
```

you typically will want to pass axis ranges which you can do like this:

```
plot(x->2x+5, xlim=(0,5), ylim=(5,15))
```

you can also plot several functions at once:

```
plot([sin, cos, x->x^2-1], label=["sin", "cos", "x²-1"], xlim=(-2,2), ylim=(-1,3))
```

The result of the last plotting command is:
[image: an example plot]

Comment: it's preferable to set the xlimits as input arguments instead: `plot(x->2x+5, 0, 5)` instead of `plot(x->2x+5, xlim=(0,5), ylim=(5,15))` . That is because the adaptive capability that calculates how many points to evaluate the function at depends on the x limits passed in (you shouldn't be getting the slight non-smoothness you can see on the green line in the plot above).

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at [Julia's documentation about plotting](https://julialang.org/downloads/plotting.html) as well as [this tutorial](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/tutorial/) found by searching `Julia plots` on a web search engine.

Plotting `y = 2x+5` in Julia v1.1 :

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("Plots") # Comment if you already added package Plots
using Plots
plotly() # Choose the Plotly.jl backend for web interactivity
x = -5:5 # Change for different xaxis range, you can for instance use : x = -5:10:5
y = [2*i + 5 for i in x]
plot(x, y, title="My Plot")
```